# jquery ui dialog does not close?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog

I cant get my dialog to close, what am I doing wrong here? I am trying to integrate this script in my asp.net mvc 3 app?

```
<p id="dialog_link" style="cursor: pointer;">
    Open Dialog
</p>
<div id="Dialog" title="Dialog title!" style="display: none;">
    @*  @{Html.RenderAction("Categories");}*@
    @{Html.RenderAction("About");}
</div>
<link href="../../Content/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type language="javascript">

    $(function () {
        var execute = function () {
            //alert('This is Ok button');
        };
        var cancel = function() {
            //alert('This is Cancel button');
            $("#Dialog").dialog('close');
        };
        var dialogOpts = {
            buttons: {
                "Ok": execute,
                "Cancel": cancel
            }
        };
        $("#Dialog").dialog(dialogOpts);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: When is not closing? When clicking `"Ok"`? Also, bearing the way you are importing the scripts and styles, you should tell if there are or not errors in your js console

Comment: You can remove the `style="display: none;"`, and instead add to `dialogOpts`: `autoOpen: false`.

Comment: @Alexender yes it is returning an error when I click on cancel: TypeError: $("#Dialog").dialog is not a function

Comment: strange because it opens the dialog anyway which is the same command ?

Comment: works fine for me..i'm usinh JQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/BWXNe/

something like this man! Hope it fits your cause!

**scripts**

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css">
```

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
                $( "#Dialog" ).dialog( "open" );    
    });

    $( "#Dialog" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 255,
            width: 300,
            buttons: {
                "Retrieve": function() {

                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
    });


});


​
```

Comment: @user603007 No worries bruv! Glad it helped you `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/FgRqx/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#dialog_link').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#Dialog").dialog({
                buttons:    {
                    'OK': function(){
                        console.log('OK clicked!');
                    },
                    'Close': function(){
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: it works fine in jsfiddle I know:) However I am trying to run it with  asp.net mvc 3?

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/piyushsardana47/26hzZ/